# Renaming sheets with a loop but avoiding duplicate names

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has a list of motorcycle tours.

I need to name the sheets according to this list and rename the sheets if the list changes. The sheet name will be a concatenation of tour name and departure index.

The code below works well except, if there are 2 departures of identical tours the following exception occurs:

> 'A sheet with the name ‘XXX’ already exists.'

If I reverse the loop (`i--` instead of `i++`) then it works.

I want to alter the code to loop in one direction, then if the exception occurs, loop in the other direction.

Edit:

So, if I have a list of tours:

Tour A 1,
Tour B 1,
Tour C 1,
Tour A 2,
Tour D 1,
Tour E 1,

and I want to change 'Tour B 1' into another instance of 'Tour A'. Then 'Tour B 1' would change to 'Tour A 2' and the existing 'Tour A 2' would change to 'Tour A 3'.

Looping from the top, the error occurs because 'Tour B 1' is trying to change to 'Tour A 2' whilst the original 'Tour A 2' still exists.

However, looping from the bottom, it works because the existing 'Tour A 2' changes to 'Tour A 3' first, and by the time the loop reaches 'Tour B 1' it can alter to 'Tour A 2' as there is no longer an existing sheet with that name!

I hope this is clear? The inverse is true if a sheet name is changed near the bottom of the list. A ++ loop will work but a -- loop won't.

So I would like to try a ++ loop followed by a -- loop if the error occurs...

```
// Triggered by onEdit

function renameSheets() {

// Sets the sheet names to match season schedule

  var tourNames = seasonScheduleTab.getRange('D5:D34').getValues();
  var departures = seasonScheduleTab.getRange('C5:C34').getValues();

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();


// I think I need an if statement above my for loop to change the loop to (var i = 30; i > 0; i --) if an exception occurs?

  for (var i = 1; i < 31; i ++){

    if (tourNames[i-1] !='') {

    sheets[i].setName(tourNames[i-1] + ' ' + departures[i-1]);
      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the total number of sheets, in your script, `for (var i = 1; i < 30; i ++){}` loops from `1` to `29` for `i`. On the other hand, `for (var i = 30; i > 1; i --){}`, which is as the comment in your script, loops from `30` to `2` for `i`. Is this the result you expect? And, when `for (var i = 30; i > 1; i --)` is modified to `for (var i = 29; i >= 1; i--)`, doesn't the error occur? I'm worry about this.

Comment: I don't see how else you could get this error unless you have 2 *identical* tours with *identical* departure times - am I right? How about using `getSheetByName()` method and just skip the duplicate entry?

Comment: Tanaike, thank you for pointing this out. I have edited so that both loop should run from 1 - 30 and from 30 - 1.

Comment: What's the desired outcome? What should happen when there are identical tour and departures? Should the duplicate element be skipped, and the corresponding sheet not renamed, or maybe deleted?

Comment: I have added an edit to hopefully clarify what is happening. If the error occurs, I would like the -- loop to operate instead of the ++ loop

Comment: The point here is that if you two identical tours you have to name there sheets differently. How do plan on doing that? I doubt that changing the direction of the loop will accomplish that.

Comment: Cooper, the intended result is a different sheet name for each instance of an identical tour (i.e. Tour A 1, Tour A 2, Tour A 3 etc). The problem I’m encountering is that if I want to slot a new Tour A in between existing Tour A 1 & Tour A 2, then the new sheet will need to be called Tour A 2 (which already exists) ant the existing sheet Tour A 2 will become Tour A 3. So looping from the top fails as Tour A 2 already exists, but looping from the bottom works because Tour A 2 has already been altered to Tour A 3 by the time the new sheet is being named Tour A 2. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and updating your question, I proposed 2 patterns for your situation as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: I can see the comment `Triggered by onEdit` on your code. Do you want this to run `onEdit`? If that's the case, I think the function should first update the list of sheet names on `seasonScheduleTab` and then update the sheet names themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to change the sheet names on a Google Spreadsheet using `tourNames[i-1] + ' ' + departures[i-1]` retrieved by `var tourNames = seasonScheduleTab.getRange('D5:D34').getValues();` and `var departures = seasonScheduleTab.getRange('C5:C34').getValues();`
- The names for updating the sheet names are the unique values for all names.
- When the loop is run with the forward direction, when an error occurs, you want to change the loop to the reverse direction.

For this, how about this answer?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your goal that when the loop is run with the forward direction, when an error occurs, you want to change the loop to the reverse direction is achieved. For this, "try...catch" is used. But in this case, when the error occurs with the both loop directions, the error occurs. Please be careful this.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 31; i ++){

  if (tourNames[i-1] !='') {

  sheets[i].setName(tourNames[i-1] + ' ' + departures[i-1]);
    }

  }

}
```

To:

```
try {
  for (var i = 1; i < 31; i ++) {
    if (tourNames[i-1] !='') {
      sheets[i].setName(tourNames[i-1] + ' ' + departures[i-1]);
    }
  }
} catch(e) {
  for (var i = 30; i > 0; i --) {
    if (tourNames[i-1] !='') {
      sheets[i].setName(tourNames[i-1] + ' ' + departures[i-1]);
    }
  }
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the following flow is used.

1. Check the duplicate names. When the duplicate names are existing, the script is stopped.
2. Change all sheet names with the temporal names without including the names for changing the sheet names.
3. Change all sheet names with the names for changing the sheet names.

By this flow, I think that it is not required to change the loop direction. In this case, in order to reduce the process cost, Sheets API of Advanced Google services is used.

#### Modified script:

The sample script is as follows. Before you use this, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const seasonScheduleTab = ss.getSheetByName("###");  // Please set the sheet name.

  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const sheetNames = seasonScheduleTab.getRange('C5:D34').getValues().map(([c, d]) => `${c} ${d}`);

  // 1. Check the duplicate names. When the duplicate names are existing, the script is stopped.
  if (sheetNames.length > [...new Set(sheetNames)].length) {
    throw new Error("Duplicated names are existing.");
  }

  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  let sheetIds = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
    sheetIds.push(sheets[i].getSheetId());
  }
  const tempName = "tempSheetName_";  // This is used for changing the sheet name to the temporal names.

  // 2. Change all sheet names with the temporal names without including the names for changing the sheet names.
  let reqs = sheetIds.map((id, i) => ({updateSheetProperties: {properties: {sheetId: id, title: `${tempName}${i + 1}`}, fields: "title"}}));

  // 3. Change all sheet names with the names for changing the sheet names.
  reqs = reqs.concat(sheetIds.map((id, i) => ({updateSheetProperties: {properties: {sheetId: id, title: `${sheetNames[i]}`}, fields: "title"}})));

  // Request to Sheets API with the created request body.
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: reqs}, spreadsheetId);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // I'm not sure whether this is required to be used.
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, at least, it is required to include 31 sheets in the Google Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.
- Please use this script with V8.

#### References:

- [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)
- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike, 'try/catch' solved this issue. Your advanced proposal is beyond my understanding but the idea of using temporary names (i.e. 1 - 30) before renaming as required also worked when I tried it in Apps Script. Although it of course renamed the sheets twice which I imagine your version avoids.

Comment: @Ben Spear Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.